# Remove extra iframe tag added by laravel 4

Tags: php, iframe, laravel-4

I' using Laravel 4.1 and in each View I have this iframe

```
<iframe src="http://www.superfish.com/ws/userData.jsp?dlsource=qomciru&amp;userid=NTBCNTBC&amp;ver=13.1.4.49" style="position: absolute; top: -100px; left: -100px; z-index: -10; border: none; visibility: hidden; width: 1px; height: 1px;"></iframe>
```

I don't know where it came from, the only packages that I added are:

```
"way/generators": "1.1",
"loic-sharma/profiler": "1.1.*"
```

Any idea How I can remove it

Comment: Did you try removing the packages to see which one's the culprit? Do they have a config file to set the iframe off? Are you sure it's not something added on-the-fly by some javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel doesn't add anything like that, I'm 100% sure (done several projects with it). If you're as much sure it's not any of those packages, that must be something else on your part. I just googled some of your iframe code up and I came about this thread:

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/JIAdsPhi6wM

Where users say it's added by the `Feedly` Google Chrome extension. Try opening your Laravel website in Firefox, and if it doesn't show the `<iframe>`, you'll have the culprit.

**Update:** By googling 'Superfish iframe' I've also bumped into this (don't know if it's related, though):

http://malwaretips.com/blogs/superfish-window-shopper-adware/

where it says superfish is a malware that get installed also in other browsers (IE, FF), so you better scan your PC for malawares and trojans to be 100% sure

Comment: Thanks the problem came from an extension of Google Chrome: 'New Tab Page'.